# Download souncloud data through API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I try to retrieve mp3 data from soundcloud through their API, I already have the download_url property and I want to save it directly to KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.
The problem is when I try to download it with browser the link ask for save/play.
Is it possible for me to bypass this and get the direct download link without have to be prompted to select save or play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried this myself but "download_url" is as you say a url to the original file. Try using this code and see what you get, then you can modify the request until you get the datastream. You could also try a proxy like Burp or Fiddler to examine what gets passed to Soundcloud and then create a similar request.

```
public static string GetSoundCloudData()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3/download");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.UserAgent =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0";
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;

    }
    else
    {
        response.Close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not directly the download file, not the xxx/xxx.mp3.
the link is something like this : https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/155949395/download

Comment: My example was "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3/download" so it is very similar. Try the code and see what you get.

Comment: thx dude I use some of your code and able to retrieve the cdn url. I Will post it on answer.

Comment: @GaneshSalim Glad it worked! You can mark the answer if you are satisfied so that the question will be green marked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HttpClient or WebClient.
As far as I remember WebClient has an OpenReadAsync method.

Use this method and pass as a parameter the mp3 url.

What you'll get back is a stream of your mp3, and then you can use a StreamWriter to save it into the local folder as a file.

Comment: I haven't try this, but i got the solution, gonna try this method and see if it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thx @Ogglas, I use some of your code and succesfully retrieve the cdn url :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
var downloadurl = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
```